# Select Data from multiple table and Group by Category

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have three tables and I want to join and get data in category wise.

```
Category Table
-id
-name

Product table
-id
-category_id
-name

Loading table
-product_id
-qty
-Outdate

Stock table
-product_id
-qty
-Indate
```

so i want to select all and sum all product regards with the spefic category_id, I expect this output

```
Category name                 open_balance      total_stock_in_jana   total_loadings_janaout
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
categori 1                    500                 0                               500
category 2                    400                 0                                400
```

but  this sql  is fetch all products wise  with their categories so I want to change it in categories

My sql

```
 SELECT 
        products.id, 
        products.name, products.open_stock as open_balance,

        (select categories.name from categories where categories.id=products.category_id) as 
         category_name,
        (select ifnull(sum(stocks.qty),0) from stocks where stocks.pid=products.id and 
          DATE(stocks.Indate) 
        <= CURDATE()-1) as total_stock_in_jana,

        (select ifnull(sum(loadings.qty),0) from loadings where loadings.pid=products.id and 
        DATE(loadings.Outdate) <= CURDATE()-1) as total_loadings_jana,

        (select ifnull(sum(stocks.qty),0) from stocks where stocks.pid=products.id and 
         DATE(stocks.Indate) 
        = CURDATE()) as total_stock_in_today,

        (select ifnull(sum(loadings.qty),0) from loadings where loadings.pid=products.id and 
        DATE(loadings.Outdate) = CURDATE()) as total_loadings_today

        from products
```

Thank you In advance

Comment: a db fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/ with sample data would be more better. bcoz there are some differences in your explanation and query

Comment: @MohammedShafeek, i can not create free DB there bro, may be i can show live DB via zoom link https://zoom.us/j/92850747357?pwd=UDYvRzV2V1Y4aG9PczVILzNXSzZsZz09

Comment: Meeting ID: 928 5074 7357
Password: 7GkdPY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query.. Here category table brought outside and added a Join with prod table in order to make a grouping.

```
SELECT categories.id, categories.name,
SUM(products.open_stock) AS open_balance,
SUM( (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(stocks.qty),0) FROM stocks WHERE stocks.pid=products.id AND stocks.Indate <= CURDATE()-1) ) AS total_stock_in_jana,
SUM( (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(loadings.qty),0) FROM loadings WHERE loadings.pid=products.id AND loadings.Outdate <= CURDATE()-1) ) AS total_loadings_jana,
SUM( (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(stocks.qty),0) FROM stocks WHERE stocks.pid=products.id AND stocks.Indate = CURDATE()) ) AS total_stock_in_today,
SUM( (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(loadings.qty),0) FROM loadings WHERE loadings.pid=products.id AND loadings.Outdate = CURDATE()) ) AS total_loadings_today
FROM categories INNER JOIN products ON categories.id = products.category_id GROUP BY categories.id;
```